# Telluric Interference data

Tags: astropy

I am looking to create a function to correct for telluric interference and to do so I need to find data on Ozone interference. 
It has been suggested to me that Astropy may have a function that does a similar thing and it would probably retrieve data of a high quality. 
Does anyone know if such a thing exists and if so, how to determine where it is looking to get that data?

Thank you!
(I am new to python and astronomy as a whole so please take it easy on me if that's a bad question)